# Can't able to compile project which was working on the previous day

Tags: android, compilation

Showing error Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':sp:spDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not determine artifacts for com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0: Skipped due to earlier error

I have cleaned the build
rebuild the project
uninstalled the Android Studio and reinstalled the Android Studio
still not working
I was working previous day
without any change of code it suddenly can't able to compile the project
I don't what is wrong with Android Studio all of a sudden.
Really frustrated please help

Comment: "Skipped due to earlier error" -- what is the earlier error?

Comment: well that is all info that is given on the build log

Comment: 6:30 PM Gradle sync failed: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':sp:spDebugRuntimeClasspath'.
    Could not determine artifacts for com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0: Skipped due to earlier error (4 m 13 s 651 ms)

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your repositories to this:

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
  google()
  jcenter()
}
```

If it doesn't work, delete the Gradle cache folder( ~/.gradle/caches).

If you still have the problem, manually delete the App build folder and clean and rebuild the project.

Finally, try a different version of the library, upgrade if there is a new version, or downgrade to an older version if you are on the latest version.

in your case, try the latest version:

```
dependencies {

  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.14.2'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.14.2'
}
```

Comment: Still not working
tried deleting the whole .gradle
and tried re-download it still the same issue
it is happening on my both the system on mac and also on windows
same thing is happening for my different project.

Comment: I updated my answer, did you try using different version,  sometimes a specific version gets opt-out due to some issues.